# Get a cell value from a different worksheet in Excel to use it in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using VBA macro in excel to transfer date to my mail but I want to use value of cells that are in a different sheet in the same workbook. How do I get them?

I tried this : `Worksheets("sheet 6").Range("B27")` but it didn't work.
Also tried `Worksheets("Salaris").Range("B27")` because "salaris" is the name of the sheet but it didnt work.

VBA compile Syntaxerror

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sk94e.png)

```
  'On Error Resume Next

    With OutMail
    .To = "" ' Either an email address or a cell value that contains an email address: ActiveSheet.Range("B11").Value
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Body = "Geachte heer, mevrouw," & vbNewLine & _
    " " & vbNewLine & _
    "De volgende kasbankopdrachten staan klaar in Kasweb onder rekeningnummer........ Ik verzoek u ze te valideren." & vbNewLine & _
    "Bijgaand ontvangt u het boedeloverzicht, tevens treft u hieronder de berekening van het nog te innen bewindvoerdersalaris en onkosten." & vbNewLine & _
    ActiveSheet.Range("C4").Value & Space(3) & ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Value & Space(10) & ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Value & Space(20) & ActiveSheet.Range("C27").Value & Space(5) & ActiveSheet.Range("B27").Value & vbNewLine & _
    ActiveSheet.Range("C4").Value & Space(3) & ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Value & Space(10) & ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value & Space(15) & ActiveSheet.Range("C26").Value & Space(5) & ActiveSheet.Range("B26").Value & vbNewLine & _

    " " & vbNewLine & _

    "Salaris volgens vonnis (incl. 21% BTW)" & Space(14) & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Salaris").Cells("42, P").Value & vbNewLine & _
    vbEndLine & _

    .Subject = ActiveSheet.Range("C4").Value & Space(3) & ActiveSheet.Range("C5").Value & Space(3) & ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Value
    .Display
    .Attachments.Add PdfFile  ' 
End With
On Error GoTo 0


Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on _didn't work_.  What error did you get. Also, can you post some more code to put us into context.

Comment: Yes ofcourse, I've edited the code in my post, including the error.

Comment: So there is something wrong with this line here:
& ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Salaris").Cells(42,"P").Value & vbNewLine & _
Because when deleted, it works fine.

Comment: can you post it in text instead of an image. It's much easier to work with in that way

Comment: I posted part of the code, hope that helps. Also, the code now works but as I mentioned below, I don't know how to end the body text. I thought vbendline & _ might work but obv it doens't. I'm not very good at this, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Salaris").Cells(27,"B").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

In VBA, when a line is not completely finished and you go to a newline, you need to write an underscore "_", are you sure you did this after every ampersand you wrote "&"?

Comment: Thanks for your fast respone. Yes, I'm certain I did this, it really has to do something with the name of the tab, as it's being highlighted when I get the error.

Comment: I thinkit's elsewhere: you have `"Salaris volgens vonnis (incl. 21% BTW)` which should be followed by a `"` but which isn't.

Comment: Thanks! That indeed did the trick, great stuff! Now I only need to know how to end the body mail, is there a code for that? I apologize for being such a noob in this. I tried VbEndLine but that didn't work. http://i.stack.imgur.com/rdPXB.png